# Grails OAuth2 signin Password Credentials Grant returns invalid_client

Tags: grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, postman

I am working on a basic grails app protected by OAuth2 authentication -- [code here](https://github.com/adeady/api-gateway-spring/tree/master/grails-oauth-service).  It is nothing more than what spring-security and spring-security-oauth plugins have for a getting started app.  In my bootstrap I have (as per getting started):

```
Role roleUser = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

User user = new User(
        username: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        enabled: true,
        accountExpired: false,
        accountLocked: false,
        passwordExpired: false
).save(flush: true)

UserRole.create(user, roleUser, true)

new Client(
        clientId: 'my-client',
        authorizedGrantTypes: ['authorization_code', 'refresh_token', 'implicit', 'password', 'client_credentials'],
        authorities: ['ROLE_CLIENT'],
        scopes: ['read', 'write'],
            redirectUris: ['http://example.com']
).save(flush: true)
```

I am trying to understand the OAuth login flow following the example flows listed in the [documentation](http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/guide/single.html#exampleFlows).

Whenever I try to authenticate using the ["Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant"](http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/guide/single.html#password) with this request:

```
$ curl -X POST -d "client_id=my-client" \
    -d "grant_type=password" -d "username=user" \
    -d "password=password" -d "scope=read" \
     http://localhost:9090/grails-oauth-service/oauth/token
```

I get the following message:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Bad client credentials"}
```

What am I doing wrong?  How would I (or my client) correctly make a single call to authenticate to the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's amazing what sleep can do to solve a problem.  Came in ready to recreate the whole setup figuring I messed something up following the getting started guides.

Started from the plugin download page and looked at the latest plugin version:

spring-security-oauth2-provider:2.0-**RC5**

and checked that against my app where for some reason I had

spring-security-oauth2-provider:2.0-**RC3**

I upgraded the plugin, re-ran the `s2-init-oauth2-provider` script, fired it up and the curl post above WORKED!  Glancing through the [change log](http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/guide/introduction.html#changes)  for RC-5 I see

> Resolve minor problems affecting stateless access of OAuth 2.0 resources

So basically I was running into a bug with that version of the oauth provider plugin.  Fun times.

Comment: Hello @adeady, Did you try to separate your authorization and provider services in Grails in two applications?